# How to read this ROC curve and set custom thresholds?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, roc

Using this code :

```
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = [1,0,0]
y_predict = [.6,.1,.1]

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_predict , pos_label=1)

print(fpr)
print(tpr)
print(thresholds)

# Print ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
plt.show()


y_true = [1,0,0]
y_predict = [.6,.1,.6]

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_predict , pos_label=1)

print(fpr)
print(tpr)
print(thresholds)

# Print ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
plt.show()
```

the following roc curves are plotted :

[image]

scikit learn sets the thresholds but I would like to set custom thresholds.

For example, for values :

```
y_true = [1,0,0]
y_predict = [.6,.1,.6]
```

The following thresholds are returned :

```
[1.6 0.6 0.1]
```

Why does value 1.6 not exist in ROC curve ? Is threshold 1.6 redundant in this case as the probabilities range from 0-1 ? Can custom thresholds be set : .3,.5,.7 to check how well the classifier performs in this case ?

Update :

From https://sachinkalsi.github.io/blog/category/ml/2018/08/20/top-8-performance-metrics-one-should-know.html#receiver-operating-characteristic-curve-roc I used same x and predicted values :

```
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = [1,1,1,0]
y_predict = [.94,.87,.83,.80]

fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_predict , pos_label=1)

print('false positive rate:', fpr)
print('true positive rate:', tpr)
print('thresholds:', thresholds)

# Print ROC curve
plt.plot(fpr,tpr)
plt.show()
```

which produces this plot :

[image]

Plot is different to referenced plot in blog, also thresholds are different :

[image]

Also, the thresholds returned by using scikit `metrics.roc_curve` implemented are : `thresholds: [0.94 0.83 0.8 ]`. Should scikit return a similar roc curve as is using same points ? I should implement roc curve myself instead of relying on scikit implementation as results are different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thresholds won't appear in the ROC curve. The scikit-learn documentations says:

> thresholds[0] represents no instances being predicted and is arbitrarily set to max(y_score) + 1

If `y_predict` contains `0.3, 0.5, 0.7`, then those thresholds will be tried by the  `metrics.roc_curve` function.

Typically these steps are followed while calculating `ROC` curve

**1. Sort `y_predict` in descending order.**

**2. For each of the probability scores (lets say τ_i) in `y_predict`, if `y_predict` >= τ_i, then consider that data point as positive.**

P.S: *If we have N data points, then we will have N thresholds (if the combinations of `y_true` and `y_predict` is unique)*

**3. For each of the `y_predicted` (τ_i) values, calculate TPR & FPR.**

**4. Plot ROC by taking `N` (no. of data points) TPR, FPR pairs**

You can refer [this blog](https://sachinkalsi.github.io/blog/category/ml/2018/08/20/top-8-performance-metrics-one-should-know.html#receiver-operating-characteristic-curve-roc) for detailed information

Comment: The graph what you have plotted is correct. I had plotted typical looking ROC. Next to that plot, I have added a `P.S: The example (TPR,FPR) pairs have not been plotted in the above graph`. Whatever the thresholds return by `metrics.roc_curve` function is correct. You can go with that. I don't think there is a need to implement your own custom `roc_curve` function